# Family law protections offered by EU Citizenship

Tags: european-union, family-law

As a United States Citizen living in an EU country, would I be offered any additional protections in family law cases if I became an EU citizen?

What if my EU citizenship was of a neighboring country, but not the one I was residing in?

For example, if an bitter ex-spouse came after me to take full custody of our children without cause. As a US citizen, I feel like I would have the odds against me and perhaps not offered the same legal support as an EU citizen would have. Or am I paranoid?

Comment: I suspect that it depends on the country, as a matter of bias rather than of law.

Comment: EU law is even less streamlined than US law: each member state has full rights to regulate everything differently and how to implement the EU laws - which are at best minimum standards. *Family Law* is one of the *least* regulated area by the EU parliament.